# Laravel & VueJS: can't read csrf token from meta tag

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am using VueJS and Laravel, and in console it shows `CSRF token not found: https://laravel.com/docs/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token`, but I added it in head in meta tag

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="{{ app()->getLocale() }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <title>Vicoteka</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="{{ url('images/logo.png') }}">

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arimo|Lobster" rel="stylesheet">  
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}">
    <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.7/js/all.js"></script>
</head>
<body class="bg-grey-lighter leading-normal">
    <div id="app">

        @yield('content')
        @include('components/footer')

    </div>
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Am I missing something? I didn't change anything in app.js, and it worked when there was no @yield and @include, but it doesn't work now even when i comment it out

Comment: This page is loading/submitting some `form`?

Comment: Nope, it just iterates through posts, and includes header and sidebar

Comment: Yes, you're missing what's in `js/app.js` ... We cant see how you're trying to get that token.